# LNK1120 on using lineSetAppPriorityW

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows XP SP3 machine and I have code that contains the following line :-

> lineSetAppPriorityW((LPWSTR )lpszAppFilename,NULL, &ExtensionID,LINEREQUESTMODE_MAKECALL,NULL,NULL);

The error I get is :-

`main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lineSetAppPriorityA@24 referenced in function _main`

Is there something obviously wrong that I'm doing? I'm trying to make a console application and I've verified that the right kind of the project has been selected.

If there's any more information that I can provide, to help diagnose the problem, please feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linker error stating it was unable to locate definition of `lineSetAppPriorityW()` function.

Link with `Tapi32.lib` to resolve this.